# calculator with Fractures and In android

Tags: android, calculator

i have to do a calculator,where i have to use functions like 1+6(4*5) can,t do the braces part can any one help me out and use Fractures

[Fractional Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.senecacreeksoftware.fractionalcalculator)

how can do this?

Comment: I think you mean *fractions*. I wouldn't use a calculator capable of causing fractures.

Comment: everything is possible in android